# Easiest Way to Convert Audio File to PCM Array

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio

What's the easiest way to convert an arbitrarily-formatted audio file to an array of PCM data?

I'm aware of two options from the `AudioToolbox` framework: `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` and `AudioConverterConvertComplexBuffer`.

`Convert` is apparently "only appropriate for PCM-to-PCM conversions where there is no sample rate conversion" and `Fill` is leaky and complicated. There's got to be an easier way to get a PCM array out of an existing audio file using CoreAudio APIs without rewriting the wheel. Anyone?

Comment: Have you looked at AVAssetReader?